# Reading in lines of text from a rich text box

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a small application for myself that concatenates some statements based on text that is entered into a couple rich text boxes on a form.

One text box may have 10-20 lines of text, and each line is it its own separate entry, so I need to be able to read the text line-by-line.

However, when researching WPFs, I have only seen one statement on the net in regards to reading text and it is reading the content of the box from start to finish. I would like to somehow loop through it or separate it line-by-line.

According to MSDN, to extract text from a WPF rich text box into a string, you need to use:

```
string StringFromRichTextBox(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
      // TextPointer to the start of content in the RichTextBox.
      rtb.Document.ContentStart, 
      // TextPointer to the end of content in the RichTextBox.
      rtb.Document.ContentEnd
    );

    // The Text property on a TextRange object returns a string 
    // representing the plain text content of the TextRange. 
    return textRange.Text;
}
```

However, if you were to look at my rich text box, you would see that the text inside is a list of values, so for instance, one box may look like below:

```
000423523

324

93489290099

823342342

0003242342

44400298889
```

I want to be able to read those values line by line within the `RichTextBox`, but in WPF, there doesn't seem to be a `richtextbox1.Lines` option.

Comment: why not read the entire contents and then parse that line by line?

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

To read lines of a WPF RichTextBox you can use the following code.

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd); 
string[] rtbLines = textRange.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine);
foreach(line in rtbLines)
{
    //do something with line
}
```

for this specific code, you will need to use the following library

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for brevity, but how about something as simple as

```
var lines = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method to split `RichTextBox` text by line-break and exclude empty lines from result set, for example :

```
String[] lines = 
        StringFromRichTextBox(rtb).Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine}
                                          , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    MessageBox.Show(line);
}
```

Comment: is the StringFromRichTextBox usable in WPF? I can't seem to get intellisense to pop that up.

Comment: hmm.. that's supposed to be your method :)